# cake php Missing Database Table

Tags: php, cakephp

I try to migrate a cake site on a new hosting.
Everything seems ok except on one sigle action.

error :
 Error: Database table actualites for model Actualites was not found.

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_table.ctp

route '/' => acceuil controller

```
<?php
class Accueil extends AppModel{
        public $name = 'Accueil';
        var $useTable = false;

        public function findPublicActualities(){

        }
}
?>


<?php
class AccueilController extends AppController{
        public $name = 'Accueil';
        public $helpers = array('Html');
        public $uses = array('Actualites');

        public function index(){
                $this->set( 'title_for_layout', 'Bienvenue' );
                $conditions = array("public" => "1");
                $actualites = $this->Actualites->find("all",
                                    array('conditions' => $conditions,
                                          'limit' => 5,
                                          'order' => 'poid ASC'));

                $this->set('actualites', $actualites);
        }
}
?>
```

thanks for your help, this issue make me crazy !

Comment: do you have any `Actualites` model ? And does the `actualites` table exist ? What result do you expect ?

Comment: Might try clearing out the temp/cache folders.

Comment: You should also try do develop completly in one language. This means you are using either english, which would make sense, because whole cake framework is in english, or you are using just French. Don't mix them. It makes your code unreadable and if one would not know that "Accueil" and "Actualites" might be the same model, which it seems to me, this code you posted just makes from half to no sense at all.
Second the cache cleaning, but only clean out the files in the folders inside "tmp/cache". Not the folders itself. And make sure they are writeable by web server user.

Answer (score 0):

in Cakephp the model name is a singular of the table name so if you have a table dogs, your model will be called Dog, so i think your problem is that you took the same model name as your table, so to fix it you can do this:

```
 class Actualites extends AppModel {
     public $useTable = 'actualites';
 }
```

and it will work.